# Asynchronous UpdatePanel within WordPress Post

Tags: ajax, wordpress, asynchronous

I am demoing bit of JavaScript in a WordPress blog post that randomly produces some content.
I'd like the user to be able to click a button and regenerate new random content via the script, and I'd like to do it asynchronously.
Does anyone have experience getting AJAX elements to work WITHIN WordPress blog posts? Or is there a simpler method to achieve an equivalent asynchronous update panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send your requests to this url - example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

with atleast one parameter as - action=[action name]

now make a plugin that has -

```
add_action('wp_ajax_[action name]', myfunction);

function myfunction()
{
  // do stuff
}
```

more details here - http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: That particular method applies only to the admin, however the link provides details for getting AJAX from the viewer side. Thanks!